# Auto configure browser video and audio permissions

Tags: audio, video, browser, webrtc

In our video conferencing HTML app (uses WebRTC), some technically challenged users are struggling to configure their browser to allow video and audio, or, more problematically, finding their way through their browser Settings to check later that it is configured correctly.

I'd like to add a button "Configure my camera and mic" and then a dialog from our HTML app would ask the user's permission to access their browser's camera and mic, and then then do it automatically for them.

For most people, the initial set up where the user just has to click the browser's Allow dialog box top left is pretty obvious, but still missed by some less savvy users, and if they have to go to their Settings to check their config later, they just call our Support instead. Any ideas for ways to automate this config would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that since that would allow any attacker to do the same.

What is not sufficient is to call getUsermedia and then hope the user understands what they need to do. You might want to check how various services do this.

https://developer.att.com/blog/3-Essential-UX-considerations-when-initiating-or-joining-a-call - while written in 2016 - remains a pretty good reference for designing the UX around that.